# How do I get the messages the HTML control is tracing to the console?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I'm using the `mx:HTML` control in an AIR application and occasionally there are errors that are traced to the console. For example, here is one of them:

> about:blank:3 HTML ERROR: Unmatched  encountered.  Ignoring tag.

and

> about:blank:16 HTML ERROR: Extra  encountered.  Migrating attributes back to the original  element and ignoring the tag.

How can I capture these errors?

Comment: In my experience, these have been one of the most frustrating situations, specially when you do not have control over the HTML page. AFAIK, there is no way to catch these (but I could be wrong), as they are probably happening in a different realm altogether outside Flex. Up voted for the  experts to shed some light!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to debug ExternalInterface through file:// from Flash Builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034375/is-it-possible-to-debug-externalinterface-through-file-from-flash-builder)